# Is $h^{-1}(C)$ a C*-algebra if $h\colon A\to B$ is a $\ast$-homomorphism between C*-algebras and $C\subset B$ is a C*-subalgebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

Is $h^{-1}(C)$ a C*-algebra if $h\colon A\to B$ is a $\ast$-homomorphism between C*-algebras and $C\subset B$ is a C*-subalgebra?

I know the image of a C*-subalgebra under a $\ast$-homomorhism is again a C*-algebra, but is it also true for preimages?

Comment: Well in general $h^{-1}(C)$ might not even be closed.

Comment: Is $h^{-1}(C)$ a norm-closed *-subalgebra of $A$? This is all you need to check

Comment: @AlonsoDelfin I think $\ast$-homomorphisms satisfy $\|h(a)\|\leq\|a\|$ for all $a\in A$ when $A$ is a C*-algebra. So they are automatically bounded (and hence continuous).

Comment: @jens you’re absolutely right! My bad!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Because $h$ is continuous, the preimage of a closed set is closed. So $h^{-1}(C)$ is closed. That it is a $*$-algebra follows easily from the fact that $h$ is s $*$-homomorphism.